# IcCube - Use a slice of the Cube as Perspective

Tags: perspective, iccube

I would like to have a slice of my Cube as a Perspective. So I don't just want to hide some members, but have all parents and other dimensions being recalculated accordingly in that Perspective. Is that possible in a quick way?

So for example we have different traffic channels and I would like to show in a whole report only data, that derives from the traffic channel SEO.

Of course I could just use something like this in every chart:

```
select
from (select [traffic_channel].[traffic_channel].[SEO] on 0 from [cube])
```

But is there a way to have a Perspective doing exaclty this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how this could be done in a perspective with the current version of icCube. Seeing a part of the data is something you can do in the security.

An easier version is adding as a FILTER BY at the end of your query :

```
SELECT
...
FROM (Select {antoher filter } on 0 from [Cube] )
FILTER BY [traffic_channel].[traffic_channel].[SEO]
```

Another option is adding a javascript hook that does this for all request but it looks somehow dangerous.